# getting error of unsupported media while using exceljs library in angular

Tags: angular, exceljs

getting error of unsupported media while using exceljs library. library in angular, I was trying to download the excel file in angular ,it was working but suddenly got this error, of unsupported media , if any one is knows about the problem , solve it and if any wants more information can msg me

Comment: Add your code, please